# Controlling blinking of LED based on value returned by a function

Tags: python, function, arduino, pyserial

I wrote a code to blink LED, based on the value returned by a function. If the function "blinktheLED" returns TRUE, then the LED have to blink and if the value returned is False, then the LED don't blink. What i wanted to do is, I want the LED to blink or not blink based on the value returned by the function.  Currently when i run the code, LED just blink once and stops rather than keep on blinking as the function is returning TRUE . Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

```
set_accepted_list = set(['1','3','112','29'])
set_list_LED_id   = set(['1','3'])
def blinktheLED(set_accepted_list,set_list_LED_id):
    if len(set_accepted_list &  set_list_LED_id) >0:
        print"yes,open the gate"                  #it will print, when i run the code
        return True
    else:
        print"no,donot open the gate"
        return False 

def code_controlling_gate(True):
    connected = False
    ser = serial.Serial("COM11",9600)  
    while not connected:
       serin = ser.read()
       connected = True
    ser.write('1')
    while ser.read() == '1':
       ser.read()
    ser.close()
```

Arduino code:

```
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(10,OUTPUT);
Serial.write('1');
}
void loop() {
  Serial.read();
  if(Serial.available()>0){
    digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(10,LOW);
    delay(500);
  }
  else{
    Serial.available()==0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Fix the python indent plz.

Comment: @frankyjuang fixed it. Sorry for the indend

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense. When do you call the two python functions?

Comment: What do you mean by `Serial.available()==0;`?

Comment: @frankyjuang I call them in the later part of the code. I am not showing the entire code here, as its little long and the parts work fine. Also, If i am not calling the function, i will get an error showing that!

Comment: @frankyjuang it means the information coming from the serial port.

Comment: `Serial.available()==0;` makes no sense. It does nothing. And you read from serial before you even check if you have anything in the serial buffer.

Comment: Why do you have in Python a function argument called `True`?

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks as though your Arduino `loop` blinking code is running based only on the condition `Serial.available()` and has no connection at all to the value that might be coming off the serial port.  Your `Serial.read()` is at the end of that block; it should be at the beginning and you should blink or not blink based on the **value** you receive.

I'm not sure that's the only problem here, but certainly you need to make that change to make it work as you describe.

More tips:

1. Make sure your serial sender is sending what you think by using a terminal emulator or a trusted device to verify that you're sending what you think you're sending.  You can tinker with the Arduino side all day long and if your sender isn't sending the right data, you'll just be frustrated.  Another PC and a null modem cable can be invaluable here.
2. Make sure all the serial parameters are the same.  speed, parity, databits all have to match.  Check both sides of the connection to make sure.  I don't see anywhere in your code where you're setting databits, parity or stopbits.
3. Once you get this working, if you have other projects that will use serial communications, consider making an Arduino that does just this -- make it a trusted device so that you can rule out these problems with a trusted device.  I have a microcontroller on a permanent board set up to do exactly this, blink when it's getting 9600 bps serial traffic.  That's my RS232 Hello World" device.  ;)
4. On the Arduino side, consider commenting out the conditional code around the blinking so that the `loop` does **nothing** but blink the LED the way you want.  That way you know at least that is working.  Like:

   ```
   digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
   delay(500);
   digitalWrite(10,LOW);
   delay(500);
   ```
5. Finally, in your code, you're doing a `Serial.read()` but not saving the value anywhere to compare it.  You only need one character to save off a '1' or '0' so assign the result of `Serial.read()` to a variable and then act on its value in your loop.

Comment: I made the edits as suggested. What you mentioned above is exactly, what i want to do. Can you suggest on how to proceed?

Comment: If the function 'code_controlling_gate(True):' returns a value, then the gate will be opened. Do u think this part have any bug?

Comment: @Georgeluke I don't have the equipment on hand to set up an environment like yours, but I'll include some more tips in my answer.